# Workflow does not execute through code but does execute otherwise + sharepoint 2007

Tags: sharepoint-2007, sharepoint-designer

I created a workflow through Sharepoint Designer 2007 that simply updates a list item when a change is made to a particular list item.

But the workflow executes when I make changes to the list item through Browser. But when same changes are made through code, it does not execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was accessing the link with Elevated Privileges, i.e. through System Account. Due to Security reasons, Workflows dont run under System Account.

I had to impersonate as a user to access and modify the list. And workflow executed.